# Why is jest running my Typescript test twice and always failing once?

Tags: typescript, testing, jestjs, ts-jest

I am writing a test in my backend to test a simple route of my API. I am using Typescript and Jest to write the test and it is all happening inside of a docker container which I start by using `docker-compose`.

I have a helper class for my tests, which creates an instance of a express webserver and a database connection via the init function. In the shutdown function it closes the connection etc.
So my test looks like this:

```js
import { Helper } from "./helper";
import request from 'supertest'

describe('article', () => {
    const helper = new Helper();
    beforeAll(async () => {
        await helper.init();
    });

    afterAll(async () => {
        await helper.shutdown();
    });

    it('should test if reaching the api is possible', async (done) => {
        request(helper.app)
        .get('/test')
        .send()
        .set('Accept', 'application/json')
        .expect(200)
        .end( (error, response) => {
            if(error) throw error;
            expect(response.body.message).toBe("Hello");
        });
    });
```

To execute the test, I use this script `"test": "jest --verbose --forceExit --runInBand --detectOpenHandles"`

If I execute the test like this, I get the following output:

[image: testOutput]

I changed the Timeout as proposed, but it didnt make a difference.
Now for testing purposes I made my route return "Helloo" instead of the expected "Hello".
This is the output that I recieve:

[image: newTestOutput]

So it obviously gets a response. My Question is, why is it running the test twice and why does it always timeout at the second test?

This is my `jest.config.js`

```js
module.exports = {
    "roots": [
      "<rootDir>/src"
    ],
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.tsx?$": "ts-jest"
    },
    "testRegex": "(/__tests__/.*|(\\.|/)(test|spec))\\.tsx?$",
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "ts",
      "js"
    ],
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**

Since this question is getting some attention recently, I removed the solution from the question text and added it to this answer.
I am not sure if this is/was the right approach and if I did something redundant, since I used jest for the second time and have not touched it ever since. But at the time I posted the question, this solved my problem:

I had to surround the expectations with a try-catch block, dont mark the test as async but pass done function in and call the done function after the expectations and in the catch block aswell.

Answer (score 0):

When using async tests you could call the [`done` callback](https://jestjs.io/docs/asynchronous#callbacks) from the body of your async handler.

something like this should do it:

```
it('should test if reaching the api is possible', (done) => { // << async tests have the done callback declared here
        request(helper.app)
        .get('/test')
        .send()
        .set('Accept', 'application/json')
        .expect(200)
        .end( (error, response) => {
            if(error) {
              done(error);
            } else {
              expect(response.body.message).toBe("Hello");
              done();
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: I tried it out and it still does not pass the test. There is a different log though:
It is not proposing the timeout anymore, now it says: 

` Test functions cannot both take a 'done' callback and return something. Either use a 'done' callback, or return a promise.
    Returned value: Promise {}`

Comment: maybe that `return` after the done(error) line is not right... Ill update. could you try again? I would need more of the source to say why exactly the tests is running twice, but my gut felling is that the test file is loaded twice (check the includes using this file)

Comment: I removed the return after done(error) since my last comment. I also searched for the file references, but none are found. What else can I provide to you of my sources? I would add it to the Question. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I just found out that it does not matter what I test, it always happens. For example I just tried the test `test('xxx',  () => { expect(1).toBe(2)})` and it has the same behaviour as described above (2 x executed, first says expected 2 received 1 and second says exceeded timeout of 5000ms for a test).

Comment: This is not an answer. async/await tests do not need a `done()` callback. https://jestjs.io/docs/asynchronous#asyncawait

Comment: @TheFabio Sorry but you're mistaken. Read https://jestjs.io/docs/asynchronous#asyncawait - none of the async/await examples use 'done' - when you await something, you're awaiting for the promise to resolve. Once the await is finished, the promise has resolved. There's no need for 'done'.

Comment: I updated the answer with a direct [link](https://jestjs.io/docs/asynchronous#callbacks) to the "done" explanation from the jest docs, so people can find-out if this answer is useful for their use-case from the source, as the info in these last comments is a little short sighted...